# SQL SERVER 2005 slow Performance on Windows Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005, migration

Recently I have upgraded my server to new one. But because of compatibility issues with my old `Windows Server 2003 R2 32 bit`, I have also upgraded it to `Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit`.

(I have install `Windows Server 2003 32 bit` & `SQL Server 2005 32 bit` on new hardware and run without problem though sometimes Windows freezes because of compatibility issue with the new hardware).

After upgrade to `Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit`, I still use the old `SQL Server 2005 R2 32 bit`. I can install SQL Server 2005 R2 32 bit on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit and make it run. The problem is that it runs slower than on my old Windows 2003.

What I did for this migration:

- Detached the LDF & MDF file and kept a backup.
- Install new Windows and SQL Server instance.
- Attached back the LDF & MDF file.

Is there anything I have missed or is there also compatibility issue using 32 bit SQL Server running on 64 bit Windows Server?

Comment: What specifically runs slower? Queries, Management Studio, maintenance jobs?

Comment: Running SQL Server 32 on 64 bit has increased VAS to 4 G for SQL Server make sure to change max server memory. Are you using AWE. After migration did you updated stats. `What Actually is slow can you be more precise`